# Kidushin with food from someone else's banquet

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, hachnasat-orchim-guests, kiddushin-eirusin

I heard that a person can perform kidushin with the food of someone else's banquet, when he's been invited as a guest.

Is this true? If so, why? (Do the owners of the banquet relinquish ownership over the food?) And where is the source for this?

Comment: You can do Kidushin with any object of yours that's a certain value. You 'acquire' your portion of the meal as a guest. The food is now yours. Why wouldn't you be able to do Kidushin with it?

Comment: @Salmononius2 basically that is the question. Do the owners of the banquet relinquish ownership over the food?

Comment: I haven't seen the sources in a while, but I don't recall that it's that simple -- if I remember correctly, there was some disagreement on the topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Rama*, *Even Haezer* 28:17, in my own loose translation:

> A guest sitting in someone's home who takes his portion of food and weds with it — she is wed.

However, *Bes Sh'muel* there cites *Bach* and *Taz* as saying that marriage is effected only *misafek* (possibly).